# Fixing file path on Windows with Win API or Boost

Tags: windows, winapi, boost

I am having the following path:

"D:\Dir1\Dir2\..\..\..C:\Dir3\Dir4"

Is there any way to fix this path with boost or Win API so I will get only "C:\Dir3\Dir4"?

I tried use boost::filesystem::absolute but it did not help.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [`PathCanonicalize` Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773569%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). From its description:

> Simplifies a path by removing navigation elements such as "." and ".." to produce a direct, well-formed path.

And here's some sample code and output, also copied from that MSDN link:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Shlwapi.h"

using namespace std;

int main( void )
{
// Path_1 destination buffer.
char buffer_1[MAX_PATH] = "JustABufferToHoldTheCanonicalizedPathForAnExample";
char *lpStr1;
lpStr1 = buffer_1;

// Path_2 to be Canonicalized.
char buffer_2[ ] = "A:\\name_1\\.\\name_2\\..\\name_3";
char *lpStr2;
lpStr2 = buffer_2;

// Path_3 to be Canonicalized.
char buffer_3[ ] = "A:\\name_1\\..\\name_2\\.\\name_3";
char *lpStr3;
lpStr3 = buffer_3;

// Path_4 to be Canonicalized.
char buffer_4[ ] = "A:\\name_1\\name_2\\.\\name_3\\..\\name_4";
char *lpStr4;
lpStr4 = buffer_4;

// Path_5 to be Canonicalized.
char buffer_5[ ] = "A:\\name_1\\.\\name_2\\.\\name_3\\..\\name_4\\..";
char *lpStr5;
lpStr5 = buffer_5;

// Path_6 to be Canonicalized.
char buffer_6[ ] = "C:\\..";
char *lpStr6;
lpStr6 = buffer_6;

cout << "The un-canonicalized path 2 is : " << lpStr2
     << "\nThe return value is            : " 
     << PathCanonicalize(lpStr1,lpStr2)
     << "\nThe canonicalized path 1 is    : " << lpStr1 << endl;

cout << "\nThe un-canonicalized path 3 is : " << lpStr3
     << "\nThe return value is            : " 
     << PathCanonicalize(lpStr1,lpStr3)
     << "\nThe canonicalized path 1 is    : " << lpStr1 << endl;

cout << "\nThe un-canonicalized path 4 is : " << lpStr4
     << "\nThe return value is            : " 
     << PathCanonicalize(lpStr1,lpStr4)
     << "\nThe canonicalized path 1 is    : " << lpStr1 << endl;

cout << "\nThe un-canonicalized path 5 is : " << lpStr5
     << "\nThe return value is            : " 
     << PathCanonicalize(lpStr1,lpStr5) 
     << "\nThe canonicalized path 1 is    : " << lpStr1 << endl;

cout << "\nThe un-canonicalized path 6 is : " << lpStr6
     << "\nThe return value is            : " 
     << PathCanonicalize(lpStr1,lpStr6)
     << "\nThe canonicalized path 1 is    : " << lpStr1 << endl;
}
OUTPUT:
---------
The un-canonicalized path 2 is : A:\name_1\.\name_2\..\name_3
The return value is            : 1
The canonicalized path 1 is    : A:\name_1\name_3

The un-canonicalized path 3 is : A:\name_1\..\name_2\.\name_3
The return value is            : 1
The canonicalized path 1 is    : A:\name_2\name_3

The un-canonicalized path 4 is : A:\name_1\name_2\.\name_3\..\name_4
The return value is            : 1
The canonicalized path 1 is    : A:\name_1\name_2\name_4

The un-canonicalized path 5 is : A:\name_1\.\name_2\.\name_3\..\name_4\..
The return value is            : 1
The canonicalized path 1 is    : A:\name_1\name_2

The un-canonicalized path 6 is : C:\..
The return value is            : 1
The canonicalized path 1 is    : C:\
```

Comment: It's worth noting that all APIs exported from the *Shell Lightweight Utility Library* have a limit of `MAX_PATH` characters for path names. This may or may not be a problem in your specific case.

Comment: @Iron-Eagle Since drives can't be nested (for example, `D:\Dir1\C:\Dir2` is an invalid path no matter how you parse it), why not just manually trim off everything before the last drive letter? Windows files and folders can't have a colon in them, so you can find the last drive letter by finding its associated colon. After you've trimmed everything up to that drive letter, `PathCanonicalize` can finish the job for you.

Comment: The very fact of having two drive letters in the same path makes it a BAD path. You can easily verify this at a command prompt.

Comment: I have experience with this function and it is sadly poor. I recommend to simply not using it at all. if you need something in its genre, just do it yourself from scratch you'll do yourself a favor. references https://dutherenverseauborddelatable.wordpress.com/2012/06/19/fun-with-windows-paths/ and http://pdh11.blogspot.jp/2009/05/pathcanonicalize-versus-what-it-says-on.html the bug I face personally is unjustified erasure of leading dots (../stuff becomes stuff, in honor of what ? s/../t can be t but ../t is ../t)